# Web application in asp.net mvc and mobile application communication

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm going to build application for web (asp.net mvc) and mobile (iOS and Android). And all three of them must communicate (share data, user authorization etc.) . What is best way to this ? Using asp.net web api or azure mobile services ?

**EDIT**

I was also wondering what was best practice for scenario like this: I have data base and business logic in one project which needs to communicate whit web and mobile using service. So which technology is best to develop this service Azure or web api or smth. else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very general.

[ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is just a framework to build RESTful web services which you can host everywhere. It does not help you with your task to "communicate (share data, user authorization etc.)".

[Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) is an Azure hosted PaaS that actually provides everything you need and even more. It also provides you with ready-to-go RESTful web services that you might implement using ASP.NET Web API as well, but in addition to that it also provides support for federated identities, data sharing etc.

So, I would say since you seem to be somewhat new to this area, you should try Mobile Service, for they are very well documented and there is plenty of nice tutorials suitable for beginners, [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started/) is my favorite one.

You can also download a project template for Android and iOS after you have set up your own mobile service and just extend it. This is really a great help for beginners and hobby developers.

**UPDATE:**

Let's approach your question with some fictional scenarios for different solutions offered by Azure:

[Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) cover the scenarios where you have multiple (mobile) devices running occasionally connected applications that need to synchronize their content through the cloud.
AMS provides you with the possibility to implement the custom processing logic for data requests and updates; it hides the burden of implementing and hosting a web service. 
About 90% of the logic is set or written directly in the management portal, the rest is just the client logic.
The main purpose of this service is data sync (this is the core functionality), all other services (authentication, logging, scheduler) are just auxiliary. 
The language used for development is JavaScript, the whole development is similar to server-side development using frameworks like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

[Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/de-de/home/features/web-sites/) is the way to host your code within IIS, that usually would be a web page, but nothing hinders you on hosting your web services (Web API based or even full-fledged WCF) here as well. Azure Web Sites are easy to deploy and this is a rather cheap solution for hosting web services, provided you allow other IIS applications (from other users) to run here as well (shared instance), but you can also prioritize your application by going for a reserved IIS instance (and pay more). Sure, you can reuse most (virtually all) of your existing business logic here (unless you need something exotic like interop or shell access that can't be hosted in IIS natively). The disadvantage of this solution is that your logic will run within the context of your web service and for long running processing this might be a non-optimal solution.

[Azure Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/) allow you to defer the processing of logic rules and to decouple the logic from the service input. In this scenario you can have two kinds of roles, typically called web role and worker role. Web role provides endpoints for your services and queues the requests, the worker roles reads the queue and does processing. This allows you to fine tune your load balancing and capacity planning, increasing the number of parallel instances with web roles and worker roles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know my question is very general but I was wondering what was best practice for scenario like this: I have data base and business logic in one project which needs to communicate whit web and mobile using service. So which technology is best to develop this service Azure or web api  or smth. else

Comment: Can you please update your original question? The answer is too long for a comment.